# Can formatting with an Android device fix error -69877 (Couldn't open device) generated by Disk Utility while trying to erase USB Drive

Tags: macos, disk-utility, data-recovery, android, disk-format

I am about to reformat a PNY 128gb microSD card that I have been unsuccessfully trying to erase by using Disk Utility (Monterey OS), but this time I will be using an older Android device. The card became unreadable after I used to extend the hard drive space of an Android 13 tablet. I tried Windows 10 and Android 13 to reformat the card, but they do not even recognize the drive. I do not have an older Android device at the moment, but I would appreciate if anyone that can reproduce or has had this error and would be kind enough to report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an old Amazon tablet, Fire 7 (7th generation) based on Android 9 Pie, and voilá! It did the work and I was able to reformat the microSD card.

Answer (score 0):

A negative error code in Apple's "universe" is generally indicative of a hardware failure. The fact that Andriod 13 and Windows were as unsuccessful in formatting the card as macOS, it's highly likely that you have a failed (or failing) SD card on your hands.

I am not at all familiar with Andriod versions and can not tell whether error checking is implemented with Andriod 9.  It may just "force" format it regardless of issues that are present.  I would look at getting a new SD card to ensure my data is written properly and not chance it.

Comment: I hear what you said; however, after formatting the card with the older Android OS, I used 'First Aid' from Disk Utility (on a Mac), and it yielded that the card is working just fine. Sometimes formatting with an older and more primitive OS does the trick. Still, I will keep in mind your input. Thanks.